# How to control size of comments popup window?

Tags: comments

Is it possible to control the size of the window that is opened with `comments_popup_link()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs it is set by function that sets up script for this functionality:

[`comments_popup_script(width, height, 'file');`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comments_popup_script)